# How to clientside print/export Leaflet.js map that's using markercluster?

Tags: javascript, printing, leaflet, markerclusterer

I have a map that is being created using Leaflet.js and, in conjunction, displaying markers through markercluster.  I need to be able to print this map using JavaScript on the client side.  There is a server-side option existing today for the system, but that is being phased out.

I'm aware of the following options:

- **leaflet-easyPrint** but that just gives me a print icon to print the page through the default printer info (which then allows printing
  to pdf like any other document).

  - Doesn't really provide much value other than a print icon.
- **Leaflet.print**

  - Server-side and not an option.
- **Leaflet-image**

  - Doesn't appear to work well yet with displaying markerclusters.

PDF Specific libraries:

- **jsPDF** looks like an intriguing option but requires html2canvas or rasterizeHTML.js which both appear to have some limitations that worry me.

  - Main concern is browser compatibility as noted on each library's documentation.
- **PDFMake**

  - Appears to have more control of the layout than jsPDF but more complex code.
- Note: neither appear to work well with browserify

The existing server-side code is jasper reports but is being pulled for various reasons.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: You should probably give more explanations on why some of the listed options do not fit your need / what limitations worry you / what is incompatible with markercluster plugin / what is the being phased out server-side option.

Comment: Updated with a bit more info